# Linter Error running Flake8 See Console for more info

Tags: python, atom-editor, flake8

I'm setting up myself a new project, and I did just starting to learn Python, I'm green on this. So recently i downloaded some packages, including Flake8 which doesn't want to start. When I try to edit something at Python some pop up appears in top right corner, which shows that i got error on: 
[Linter] Error running Flake8
See Console for more info.

The "Console" how I understand, says (In the Code Section)

I tried to re-install the package, but it didn't help.

```
C:\Users\3Nematic\.atom\packages\linter\lib\linter-registry.js:155 [Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: c:\users\3nematic\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pycodestyle.py:111: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
  EXTRANEOUS_WHITESPACE_REGEX = re.compile(r'[[({] | []}),;:]')
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\3Nematic\.atom\packages\linter-flake8\node_modules\sb-exec\lib\index.js:56:20)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(anonymous) @ C:\Users\3Nematic\.atom\packages\linter\lib\linter-registry.js:155
```

Nothing changed at all.

Comment: Now i also got another problem, I can't even search for packages. Searching for “flake” failed.Show output…https://gyazo.com/5f9b00e07c8ad72ba2ac4aa4c42c2b6b

Answer (score 0):

What version of pycodestyle do you have installed? If its below 2.4.0 it may come from there.

```py
pip show pycodestyle
```

If below then run

```py
pip install --upgrade pycodestyle
```

Comment: Don't work, but another error. https://gyazo.com/525f6be2eba38788dd8f7ce603ff0fba

Comment: whats your flake8 version?

Comment: ah i see its still v2.. so maybe try pip --install --upgrade flake8

Comment: Then maybe follow https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8/issues/621